# Getting input in bash from when running at command line

Tags: bash

So I recently tried getting a string as an input in a bash script which looked a little something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while getopts s: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s|--sample) sample=${OPTARG}
        echo $sample
        ;;
    esac
done
```

<sup>The credit for most of this code goes to [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/use-command-line-arguments-in-bash-script) at 2.2.</sup>

If I try to run this code, it works, but only if I use `-s`. If I use `--sample`, it just echo's `ample`. Is there an easy way around this

Comment: @kara I have now gotten it to work, however, it still outputs `/path/to/my/files: illegal option -- -`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Your question seems to be already answered in-depth in the question marked as duplicate (so I'm voting to this one as well) → TL;DR: `getopts` only supports *short options*, not *--long-options*. But many alternatives are available, and FWIW [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297066/9164010) based on [argbash](https://argbash.io/) looks like the best solution to me for this use case.